In variational calculus, why weight function equals the variation of the primary variable $w=\delta u$
In the book, "An introduction to FEM" by J.Reddy, p32, it is stated that in the weak formulation, the weight function has the meaning of the variation of the dependent variable, i.e. in the weighted residual $(Lu-f)$ form:
$$\int w(Lu-f) = 0$$
where $w$ is a weighting function and $u$ is the dependent variable (primary variable) to be determined, we should have
$$w = \delta u$$
why?


This interpretation comes from variational calculus where we seek to extremize some integral functionals, such as energy in physical problems. First consider a finite-dimensoinal example of the form $J(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^TLx - x^Tf$, where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. For simplicity, we will assume $L$ is self-adjoint. This function is differentiable everywhere and hence we characterize its minima in the following way:

We say that $x^*$ is a local minimizer if $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{J(x^*+hv) - J(x^*)}{h} \geq 0, \ \forall v\in\mathbb{R}^n.$$

This says that $J$ obtains a minimum if its directional derivative in every direction is positive, i.e., it is increasing in every direction. However, we can also use the fact that directional derivatives can be expressed in terms of a dot product with the gradient gradient. For this function, the gradient is given by $\nabla J = Lx - f$ and a necessary condition for optimality can be obtained:
$$
\langle v, Lx-f \rangle = v^T(Lx - f) = 0, \ \forall v\in\mathbb{R}^n.
$$
Notice the structural similarity with your equation. We have an equation involving the state ($x$) against different "weights" ($v$), where $x$ and $v$ come from the same space ($\mathbb{R}^n$). This type of structure is exactly what we wish to reproduce in the infinite-dimensional case.
Now consiser the space $L^2(\Omega)$, the space of square-integrable real-valued functions over $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ along with the inner product $\langle u,v\rangle = \int_\Omega uv~\mathrm{d}x$. Assuming that $L$ and $f$ are nice and bounded, we define the functional
$$
J(u) = \int_\Omega \frac{1}{2} u(Lu) - uf~\mathrm{d}x = \left\langle u, \frac{1}{2} Lu - f\right\rangle,
$$
where again we are assuming $L$ to be self-adjoint. We are now in an infinite-dimensional space, but we can define directional derivatives in the exact same way as in fininte dimensions. Furthermore, since we no longer have nicely enumerable components of our vectors, we use the following definition of the gradient:

The gradient with respect to the $L^2(\Omega)$ inner product of a functional $J$ at a point $u$ is given by the unique element $g\in L^2(\Omega)$ satisfying $$\langle g,v \rangle = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{J(u+hv) - J(u)}{h}, \ \forall u\in L^2(\Omega).$$

That is, directional derivatives define an inner product. For this problem with self-adjiont $L$, the gradient is given by $g(u) = Lu -f$ and the natural extension of the necessary optimality condition is given by
$$
\langle g(u),v \rangle = \int_\Omega v(Lu-f)~\mathrm{d}x, \ \forall v\in L^2(\Omega),
$$
which matches the expression in your question. Notice again that $u$ and $v$ are elements of the same space and that $v$ are interpreted as perturbation directions in a direction derivative expressed as the inner product of these directions against a gradient.
Now that we have unpacked the variational context, we can answer your question. When we integrate a weak form against a weight function and requiring it to be true for all weight functions, what we are actually doing is saying "If we perturb the associated functional in any direction, this statement remains true." Not everything is expressed explicitly in erms of gradients and variational optimization, but some methods are (Ritz methods) and when we actually perform the discretization, this corresponds exactly to the gradient of the projection error onto a finite-dimensional subspace of $L^2(\Omega)$ and setting this equal to zero for all variationa in this subspace ensures that the finite element solution is optimal over our subspace.

Thank you for detailed answer. Sorry if my question seems amateur, What I got from your answer is that the weighted integral $\langle g(u),v \rangle = \int_\Omega v(Lu-f)~\mathrm{d}x, \ \forall v\in L^2(\Omega),$,  means enforcing the projection of residual to zero against all directions is equivalent to minimizing the functional. but I still don't get why $v=\delta u$  i.e. the variation of the solution of differential equation is equal to weight (not to be confused with the variation of the functional of weighted residual)

$\delta u$ has nothing to do with the solution of the PDE. The “$u$” in $\delta u$ is merely meant to signify that we are taking the variations derivative with respect to the variable $u$ as opposed to, say, $f$ and that they lie in the same space
